# How to receive an alert when a Windows Web server running IIS with no internet or SMTP connectivity is restarted?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, python, iis-8

I have 3 web servers, and I have little control over the antivirus that keeps restarting the machine at around 1am.  This causes a critical program to stop running and I'm only aware of it in the morning.  Is there a way for the server to send an email or alert or even create a file on my local machine?  All 3 of my web servers don't have internet access, nor do they have access to our SMTP server.  They only run on our internal VPN.

Comment: Since they are web servers, you probably can run a scheduled task (like hourly) from another machine (can talk to SMTP server) to check whether they are accessible and send you emails when failed. There wouldn't be a simple solution if your corporate network is too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

> I have little control over the antivirus that keeps restarting the
> machine at around

It's the first time I've ever heard such a story... you should really ask the antivirus team to stop doing that.

Use a [startup script in Group Policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn789196(v=ws.11)) so you can send an email, or write something somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you proceed according to your 3rd proposal: Write a file on the desktop of your local machine.

Make a scheduled task which will start when your computer starts (that's the name of the task trigger on create new task wizard). I suppose you can provide user and access to
`copy wasRebooted \\YourPC\c$\Users\YourUser\Desktop` successfully.

In this example whenever your server reboots will copy a file named wasRebooted to your local PC's desktop. You can also append date/time if you like.

Keep a tidy desktop with few icons :)